# Makefile command conflicts with folder name

Tags: shell, makefile, zsh

I'm having a small problem with my Makefile, where it conflicts with a folder.
First of all I'm using the Makefile to run several shell commands
Per example:

Makefile contents:

```
test:
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -R $(REPORTER) \
        $(WATCH) \
        --ui $(UI)
```

If in the same directory of the Makefile, I have a folder named `test` when I run:

```
make test
```

I get the following result:

```
make: `test' is up to date.
```

I really have no idea to explain this better, but I would gladly answer and question asking for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea what mocha is (I'm guessing it's some combination of Cocoa and Java), but try adding [this line](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) to your makefile, outside the rule:

```
.PHONY: test
```

Comment: that worked, kinda surprised about it =\ Where can I find out why did that work?

Comment: Make is comparing your rule's name with the files within the folder it executes to avoid rebuilding file which are up to date. .PHONY rule explicit on which rules this mechanism should not be applied.